# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.authentication_user

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting the error mentioned in the title during my try to save some information to a postgres database.

My `models.py` script is the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class Event(models.Model):
    
    user_id_event = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dr_notice_period = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dr_request = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`CustomeUser` is from the `models.py` of a custom authentication application:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    demo = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

My `serializers.py` script is the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from vpp_optimization.models import Event

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('__all__')
```

And my `views.py` where I am trying to add a specific event to the database is the following:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import status

from vpp_optimization.serializers import EventSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,])
def event(request):
    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user_id_event=request.user)
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The full error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.authentication_user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/vpp_optimization/views.py", line 22, in event
    serializer.save(user_id_event=request.user)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/energy_efficiency_flexibility_services/venv/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.authentication_user
```

Any idea how can I fix it and why is it caused?

Comment: Did you perform the migration?

Comment: You are using an sqlite DB not postgres

Comment: @Walucas Yes, I performed the migrations.

Comment: @IainShelvington Indeed that is what I can notice from the traceback. However, what can I do differently to force it use the postgres?

Comment: Either change your DATABASES setting so that the postgres connection is the "default" or pass the database name in the call to save - `.save(using='postgres_db')` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save